# How do I intercept all f the page traffic in a scrollable website on playwright?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright, playwright-test

So I am using the following code:

```
import { firefox } from 'playwright';
// domain
let domain = 'https://www.reddit.com/'

// create a new page
const page = await browser.newPage();
// set routes
await page.route('**', async route => {
  const response = await route.fetch();
  await route.fulfill({ response });
});
// go to the domain
await page.goto(domain);
```

When run it I can see the traffic go trough my route, but after a seomt time as I start to scroll down the reddit page I stop seeing it. I can see traffic comming in on the dev tools, but it does not get intecepted by my route.
I think it might be intercepting all of the traffic only to load the page, but not anyother requests after that. How can I intercept all of the traffic comming from and to the page.
Thank you ^^

I tried other scrollabel web apps such a tiktok with the same results.
I want to be able to route all of the traffic coming from my page.

Answer (score 1):

[Monitoring Network](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#network-events)

With playwright, you can monitor all the [Requests](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-request) and [Responses](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-response) on a page:

```
// Subscribe to 'request' and 'response' events.
page.on('request', request => console.log('>>', request.method(), request.url()));
page.on('response', response => console.log('<<', response.status(), response.url()));

// Navigate to the website
  await page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/');



// Scroll down to trigger additional requests
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the request event instead of the fetch event:

```js
  import { firefox } from 'playwright';
  const browser = await firefox.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  // Set up the request interception
  await page.route('**', async (route) => {
    const request = route.request();
    console.log('Intercepted request:', request.url());
    await route.continue();
  });

  // Navigate to the website
  await page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/');

  // Scroll down to trigger additional requests
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  });

  // Wait for a while to allow more requests to be intercepted
  await page.waitForTimeout(3000);

  // Close the browser
  await browser.close();
```